# PostgreSQL Function Type reuse

Tags: postgresql

I have one function, that returns a table. I need another function to inherit same output type, like here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t_report (pMedia text[])
  RETURNS TABLE (
    media text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   sql text;
BEGIN
   sql := 'SELECT
            tStreams.Media
        FROM
            (SELECT
                ''Audio'' as Media
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                ''Video'' as Media
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                ''App Sharing'' as Media) tStreams
            WHERE tStreams.Media in (select unnest($1))';

   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql
   USING pMedia
   ;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t_report (pMedia text)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    media text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM t_report(ARRAY[$1])' USING pMedia
   ;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT *
    FROM t_report('Audio');
```

This works fine, but I need the second function to inherit type from the first.
Is it possible to do straight or I need to create specific type and put it in as RETURNS SETOF MyType?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the use of dynamic SQL is completely useless. And you don't even need PL/pgSQL for this. A simple `language SQL` function would do just fine

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "inherit type from the first"? Are you referring to the `returns table(...)` part? If that is the case, then yes you need a custom type that defines your result

Comment: You should use `tStreams.Media = any ($1)` instead of `tStreams.Media in (select unnest($1)`  - that's way more efficient